# Java - Overriding A Parent Class

Tags: java, class, overriding, parent-child

I am new to Java and I am working on a project that works with calculating prices with/without employee discounts.  After reading the following code could someone explain to me how I would need to change my code in order to get the correct output?  I will explain this question in more detail at the end of the post.

**Parent Class (I am NOT allowed to edit this):**

```
public class GroceryBill {
    private Employee clerk;
    private List<Item> receipt;
    private double total;
    private double internalDiscount;

    public GroceryBill(Employee clerk) {
        this.clerk = clerk;
        receipt = new ArrayList<Item>();
        total = 0.0;
        internalDiscount = 0.0;
    }

    public void add(Item i) {
        receipt.add(i);
        total += i.getPrice();
        internalDiscount += i.getDiscount();
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return Math.rint(total * 100) / 100.0;
    }

    public Employee getClerk() {
        return clerk;
    }

    public void printReceipt() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    private String valueToString(double value) {
        value = Math.rint(value * 100) / 100.0;
        String result = "" + Math.abs(value);
        if(result.indexOf(".") == result.length() - 2) {
            result += "0";
        }
        result = "$" + result;
        return result;
    }

    public String receiptToString() {
        String build = "items:\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < receipt.size(); i++) {
            build += "   " + receipt.get(i);
            if(i != receipt.size() - 1) {
                build += "\n";
            }
        }
        return build;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return receiptToString() + "\ntotal: " + valueToString(total);
    }

    public String discountToString() {
        return receiptToString() + "\nsub-total: " + valueToString(total) + "\ndiscount: " + valueToString(internalDiscount) + "\ntotal: " + valueToString(total - internalDiscount);
    }

    public static class Employee {
        private String name;

        public Employee(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private String name;
        private double price;
        private double discount;

        public Item(String name, double price, double discount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.discount = discount;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public double getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }

        private String valueToString(double value) {
            String result = "" + Math.abs(value);
            if(result.indexOf(".") == result.length() - 2) {
                result += "0";
            }
            result = "$" + result;
            return result;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + valueToString(price) + " (-" + valueToString(discount) + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my code:**

```
public class DiscountBill extends GroceryBill
{
    private int myDiscountCount;
    private double myDiscountAmount;
    private double myPrice;
    
    public DiscountBill(Employee clerk, boolean preferred)
    {
        super(clerk);
        
        String name = "";
        double price = 0;
        double discount = 0;
        
        GroceryBill.Item myBill = new GroceryBill.Item(name, price, discount);
        myDiscountAmount = myBill.getDiscount();
        
        if (myDiscountAmount > 0 && preferred)
        {
            myDiscountCount++;
        }
    }

    public void add(Item myBill)
    {
        myPrice += myBill.getPrice();
        myDiscountAmount = myBill.getDiscount();

        if (myDiscountAmount > 0 )
        {
            myDiscountCount++;
        }
    }
    public double getTotal()
    {
        if (myDiscountCount > 0)
        {
            return myPrice - myDiscountAmount;
        }
        return myPrice;
    }
    public int getDiscountCount()
    {
        return myDiscountCount;
    }
    public double getDiscountAmount()
    {
        return myDiscountAmount;
    }
    public double getDiscountPercent()
    {
        return ((myPrice - myDiscountAmount) / myPrice * 100);
    }
}
```

**Lastly, [here](http://prntscr.com/7ww3f8) is the expected output followed by my specific question:**

The outputs that I am getting for my methods are one step ahead of where they should be.  That is to say, my getTotal, for example, should start out as 1.35 (the first value input by the website I am using that tests my child class that I wrote) and then after another step it should be reduced to 1.1 (the website uses the employee discount using the boolean preferred from the constructor), but my program outputs 1.1 because my child class overrides the parent class's getTotal() method and never starts at the total it should (1.35).  Basically I need to know how to get those original values from my parent class and THEN use the override methods to get the values after they are changed.  If you want to see how this website operates, [here](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building%20Java%20Programs%2C%203rd%20edition%2FBJP3%20Chapter%209&problem=bjp3-9-e10-DiscountBill) is a link to the question I'm working on.

P.S. Please let me know if I need to give more/less information and ways that I can clean up this post or make it easier to understand.  If my question was too broad, please ask me what you don't understand about it and I'll try my best to tell you!  Thank you!

Comment: `myPrice` in `DiscountBill ` and `total` in `GroceryBill` are same?

Comment: @karthik myPrice in DiscountBill is changed to accommodate employee discounts whereas total in GroceryBill is not affected by discounts.  I need to use the total for the first output and then myPrice for the rest.  My issue is my program is using myPrice the entire time and completely overriding add() and getTotal() from GroceryBill.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand your question completely, I added an answer. Just check and let me know that is what you want.

Comment: OK right, so I believe the reason my program returns 0 as the first getTotal() is because it calls the super's getTotal which recieves the total variable's value from the super constructor (which is 0.0).  So doing this doesn't call the add method from the super class which creates the first total value.  At least that's what I think is happening and I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: can you edit your question and explain how you are expecting 1.35 and what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @karthik the question has been updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84275/discussion-between-karthik-and-trafton).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, what you want to do is :

Add this additional code to your `DiscountBill`

```
public class DiscountBill extends GroceryBill
{
    private static boolean isFirstTime = true;

    public double getTotal()
    {
        if (!isFirstTime && myDiscountCount > 0)
        {
           return myPrice - myDiscountAmount;
        }
        isFirstTime = false;
        return myPrice;
    }

}
```

Comment: That made my first getTotal() return 0.0.  For some reason it didn't get 1.35 like it should.

Comment: @Trafton `I need to use the total for the first output and then myPrice for the rest`, How are you expecting `1.35`?? what is `1.35` in this case? is it `myPrice`?

Comment: the website that I am using accepts the class that I wrote and automatically tests it with it's own inputs.  The first expected output for getTotal() is 1.35, then the program tests the price again, but with an employee discount (the boolean preferred that is a parameter in my constructor in the child class).

Comment: It is very close to working!  It got past the first step this time, but now it's not being overridden by my getTotal.  Here's a screenshot of the output for getTotal now: http://prntscr.com/7wwsjf as you can see, it got past the first step, but now it is not 1.1 anymore after that first step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you want. Do you want to call parent method?
For that you can use `super.parentMethodName`
Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Please refer to Karthik's answer (and the comments below) to better understand the question I am asking.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to do that

Comment: myPrice in DiscountBill is changed to accommodate employee discounts whereas total in GroceryBill is not affected by discounts. I need to use the total for the first output and then myPrice for the rest. My issue is my program is using myPrice the entire time and completely overriding add() and getTotal() from GroceryBill.

Comment: @Trafton I think I understood your question now, I edited my answer. Check that.